# Ошибка в добавлении нового узла в список

Tags: c, список, struct, односвязный-список, динамические-структуры

Изучаю динамические структуры данных, в частности, линейный список. Вот мой код:

```
typedef struct Node {
    char word[20];
    struct Node *next;
}Node, *PNode;


PNode CreateNode(char newWord[])
{
    PNode NewNode = (PNode)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    strcpy(NewNode->word, newWord);
    NewNode->next = NULL;
    return NewNode;
}

void AddFirst (PNode Head, PNode NewNode)
{
    NewNode->next = Head;
    Head = NewNode;
}
PNode Find (PNode Head, char newWord[])
{
    PNode q = Head;
    while (q && strcmp(q->word,newWord))
        q = q->next;
    return q;
}
int main()
{
    PNode Head = NULL, p;
    char newWord[] = "1";
    p = CreateNode("2");
    AddFirst(Head, p);
    p = Find (Head, newWord);
    if (p == NULL) {
        p = CreateNode(newWord);
        AddFirst(Head, p);
    }

    while (p) {
        printf("%-20s\t\n", p->word);
        p = p->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

При запуске программы должно выводиться `2   1`, а выводит `1`. Скорее всего, я теряю где-то правильный адрес корня, но вот не пойму, где. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение. Затирание происходит потому, что теряется адрес "изменяющей" головы списка. Для этого в `AddFirst (PNode *Head, char newWord[])` в параметрах необходимо оперировать с **указателем** на PNode (указатель на структуру) и вызывать тогда

```
AddFirst(&Head,"string");
```

для получения значения указателя на структуру (так как мы **разименовываем**).

Comment: Во время выполнения всей программы Head == NULL. AddFirst(&Head,"string"); - вы передаете адрес Head который == NULL

Comment: @AndriyPoplavskiy а что вы этим хотите сказать?

Comment: Имею в виду что при вызове AddFirst(&Head,"string"); вы передаете адрес ячейки памяти в которой находится указатель "Head" который == NULL

Comment: В моем ответе внизу добавил ссылки на видео (последняя ссылка), хорошо объясняет про указатели в С (сам когда-то учился по этим видео)

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код:

```
    int main()
{
    PNode Head = NULL, p;
    char newWord[] = "1";
    p = CreateNode("2"); // создание первого элемента списка и присвоение его адреса указателю "p" т.е. указатель "p" указывает на область памяти где находится строка "2" (p->world == "2"; p->next == NULL; Head == NULL) 
    AddFirst(Head, p); // устанавливаете Head следующим элементом списка (p->world == "2"; p->next == NULL; Head == NULL) по сути ничего не изменилось
    p = Find (Head, newWord); // переходите к последнему элементу списка (на этом моменте теряете указатель на первый) (p == NULL; Head == NULL)
    if (p == NULL) { // условие выполняется потому что действительно p == NULL 
        p = CreateNode(newWord); // создаете еще один элемент списка(p->world == "1"; p->next == NULL; Head == NULL)
        AddFirst(Head, p); // снова устанавливаете Head следующим элементом списка (p->world == "1"; p->next == NULL; Head == NULL)
    }

    while (p) {
        printf("%-20s\t\n", p->word); // print списка в котором по сути один элемент (p->world == "1"; p->next == NULL)
        p = p->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Хорошие материалы можно посмотреть:

про списки [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmuZ_U_GLYY)

про структуры [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ooPdvzhhJw&t=1s)

про указатели [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmdN4RxKVqE&t=1s)